# task manager performance tab

Tags: windows, command, task-manager

I am trying to have task manager open on the Performance tab on startup on Windows 8, 8.1, and 2012 machines.  I have gotten the task manager to open, but it always does so on the Processes tab and not the Performance tab.  Can someone please help me?

I am using a cmd batch file with the following snippet to open the task manager stored in the startup folder.

start C:\Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe
exit

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this, as taskmgr.exe does not accept any arguments.

Having said that, [someone over on StackOverflow whipped up some code you could use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987130/invoking-windows-task-manager-with-performance-tab-selected) if you wanted to compile it into a small .NET program.  Seems like more trouble than it's worth to me, but your call.

Comment: you actually can open the taskmanager having the startup-tab preselected. run "taskmgr /7 /startup"